# Dreferencing struct values, but keep getting lots of errors

Tags: c, struct, compiler-errors

this is the code below. I am keep getting lots of errors during compilation, error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
     X1->data = X1->data + Y1->data;
Please help. The code is pretty simple, there are just 6 cases. Basically, I have two registers, X and Y, and a multidimensional array that holds commands and values (1000 memory location). So when user types command 101, it goes to function 'First', so it is the register X, and types the value for register X, and array memory saves this value at position [1][1], and a command to position [1][0]. 102 is for register Y.

```
#include<stdlib.h>

#include<stdio.h>

#define SIZE 1000

int first(int *counter, struct registers* X1, int m[][2])
{
 int value;
 printf("Enter the value for the X\n");
 scanf("%d", &value);
 X1->data = value;
 m[*counter][0] = 101;
 m[*counter][1] = X1->data;
 *counter = *counter++;
 return 0;
}

int second(int *counter, struct registers* Y1, int m[][2])
{
 int value;
 printf("Enter the value for the Y\n");
 scanf("%d", &value);
 Y1->data = value;
 m[*counter][0] = 101;
 m[*counter][1] = Y1->data;
 *counter = *counter++;
 return 0;
}

int main()
{
 int memory[SIZE][2];
 int count = 0;
 int choice;
 struct registers
 {  
      int data;     

 } registerX, registerY;
 printf("Enter the instruction number:\n");
 scanf("%d", &choice);
 switch(choice)
 {
   case 101:
       first(&count, &registerX, memory);
   case 102:
       second(&count, &registerY, memory);
   default:
        printf("invalid code, please try again\n");
 }


}
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: tagging a question with both C and C++ is abuse. you can't write a program in both C and C++ at the same time. this looks C rather than C++. also, this has exactly nothing to do with "performance" (tag purged).

Comment: Well I thought that is has to do with the performance, while getting help from the answers I could enhance my code. Secondly, who knows C++ pretty much knows how C works, so I thought that this kind of simple code wouldn't be a problem for C++ programmers.

Answer (score 1):

```
struct registers
 {  
      int data;     

 } . . . . .
```

This is local to `main()`. Define it in global scope.